# LaTeX minipage on same page

Tags: minipage

I want to take two `minipage` environments on same page next to each other but (I do not know why) not work.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{blindtext}
 \usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
 
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
\blindtext[1]
\end{minipage}
\vline

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\blindtext[1]
\end{minipage}
\vline
 
\end{document}
```

What is the solution?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minipage is positioned by the same code as a letter, so each of those minipages is indented by `\parindent` and has a paragraph break between them so they stack vertically. If you want them side by side remove the blank line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{blindtext}
 \usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
 
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
\blindtext[1]
\end{minipage}
\vline{}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\blindtext[1]
\end{minipage}
\vline
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! :)

Comment: @coder1234 note I added `{}` after the vline so you get a space after it to match the space before it.